# How do you turn the PDT response from PayPal into a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I'm trying to use the PDT system on PayPal to manage payments on my site. My site is correctly receiving the transaction id which is sent back to paypal in order to receive the transaction data.

This is the code which I am using to post the transaction id to paypal and receive a response.

```
response = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse("#{Rails.application.secrets.paypal_host}/cgi-bin/webscr?"), values)
    puts response.body
```

I am receiving the correct response where response.body shows this in the terminal.

```
SUCCESS
transaction_subject=SPORTS+PACKAGE+%281+Week%29
payment_date=23%3A32%3A01+Jul+20%2C+2017+PDT
txn_type=subscr_payment
subscr_id=I-WHFVMBY57NX2
last_name=Lucas
residence_country=US
item_name=SPORTS+PACKAGE+%281+Week%29
payment_gross=
mc_currency=AUD
business=merchant-success%40puntsquad.com
payment_type=instant
protection_eligibility=Ineligible
payer_status=verified
payer_email=buyer-success%40puntsquad.com
txn_id=8M5887849L359363Y
receiver_email=merchant-success%40puntsquad.com
first_name=George
payer_id=667TSNBH7R7X4
receiver_id=WJYE8WGSREP98
payment_status=Completed
payment_fee=
mc_fee=2.00
mc_gross=50.00
charset=windows-1252
```

My problem is I am unsure of how I am able to access these values.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the response body to a hash as follows

```
hsh = CGI::parse(response.body)
puts hsh['transaction_subject']
```